# (C) popen(79172,0x114108dc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffee0155ad0: pointer being freed was not allocated and another error

Tags: c

What do these errors mean and how can I fix them?

```
popen(79172,0x114108dc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffee0155ad0: pointer being freed was not allocated
popen(79172,0x114108dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    while (1){
        char* command; //= (char *) malloc(128*sizeof(char));
        char* output = (char *) malloc(4096);
        printf(">> ");
        scanf("%[^\n]", command);
        FILE* cmd = popen(command, "r");
        fread(output, sizeof(output), sizeof(cmd), cmd);
        fputs(output, stdout);
        if (strlen(output) != 0){
            printf("\n%s\n", output);
        free(output);
        free(command);
        pclose(cmd);

        }
    }
}
```

and here is the I/O:

```
>> ls
Applications
Creative Cloud Files
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Dr
Applications
Creative Cloud Files
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Dr
popen(79172,0x114108dc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffee0155ad0: pointer being freed was not allocated
popen(79172,0x114108dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
```

Comment: Nowhere in this code is a valid memory region (dynamic or otherwise) assigned to `command`. You are, however, sending an indeterminate value from said-same to `scanf`, and therefore invoking *undefined behavior*. Why you/someone chose to comment out `//= (char *) malloc(128*sizeof(char));`, which was clearly being used to initialize `command` prior is a question best-answered by the person that did it. And fyi, `sizeof(command)` most certainly won't do what you want, and `sizeof(cmd)` (where `cmd` is a `FILE*`) appears to be  guesswork, as it has no reason being where you're using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> popen(79172,0x114108dc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffee0155ad0: pointer being freed was not allocated
> popen(79172,0x114108dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
> ```

*command* is not initialized, the behavior is undefined when it is used by *scanf* and of course after in *popen*

I encourage you to compile with option for warning, for instance :

```
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ gcc -Wall p.c
p.c: In function ‘main’:
p.c:10:9: warning: ‘command’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
         scanf("%[^\n]", command);
         ^
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$
```

An other problem in that line is even *command* initialized to point to a block of memory you do not protect the length set by *sscanf* so it may write out of the buffer with an undefined hebavior

This line is also invalid

> ```
>    fread(output, sizeof(output), sizeof(cmd), cmd);
> ```

*output* is declared as a *char** so *sizeof* return the size of a pointer whatever the size of the allocated block it may value, and independently of that this is not compatible with *sizeof(cmd)* whose must be a number of element.

After when you read the result with *fread(output, sizeof(output), sizeof(cmd), cmd);* you cannot be sure you read all , you need to use a loop up to EOF

When you use a function like *scanf*, *fread*, *popen* etc I encourage you to check the return value to detect error

Here an example  :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  char cmd[256];

  if (fgets(cmd, sizeof(cmd), stdin) == NULL) {
    puts("EOF");
    return -1;
  }

  FILE * fp = popen(cmd, "r");

  if (fp != 0) {
    char s[64];

    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), fp) != NULL)
      fputs(s, stdout);

    pclose(fp);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions:

```
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ gcc -Wall c.c
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ ./a.out
date
samedi 11 avril 2020, 22:59:23 (UTC+0200)
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ ./a.out
date | wc
      1       6      42
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ ./a.out
cat c.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  char cmd[256];

  if (fgets(cmd, sizeof(cmd), stdin) == NULL) {
    puts("EOF");
    return -1;
  }

  FILE * fp = popen(cmd, "r");

  if (fp != 0) {
    char s[64];

    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), fp) != NULL)
      fputs(s, stdout);

    pclose(fp);
  }

  return 0;
}
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$
```

If you absolutely want to allocate in the heap you can do for instance :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LENGTH 256

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  char * buffer = malloc(LENGTH);

  if (buffer == NULL) {
    puts("not enough memory");
    return -1;
  }

  if (fgets(buffer, LENGTH, stdin) == NULL) {
    puts("EOF");
    free(buffer);
    return -1;
  }

  FILE * fp = popen(buffer, "r");

  if (fp != 0) {
    while (fgets(buffer, LENGTH, fp) != NULL)
      fputs(buffer, stdout);

    pclose(fp);
  }

  free(buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ gcc -Wall c.c
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ ./a.out
date
samedi 11 avril 2020, 23:07:01 (UTC+0200)
```

Execution under *valgrind*

```
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$ valgrind ./a.out
==12851== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12851== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12851== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12851== Command: ./a.out
==12851== 
date
samedi 11 avril 2020, 23:07:14 (UTC+0200)
==12851== 
==12851== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12851==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12851==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 6,656 bytes allocated
==12851== 
==12851== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12851== 
==12851== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12851== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
bruno@bruno-XPS-8300:/tmp$
```